# How can I change the text: "Images must be larger than 200x200" in the image field for a specific content type?

Tags: entities, media

How can I change or replace the text: "Images must be larger than 200x200" in the image field for a specific content type?

I have created a image field CCK and I have put the Minimum resolution for Images of 200x200.  When I put this restriction appears the text:   Images must be larger than 200x200.  I need to replace or change this text by:  Minimum size for images:  200x200, in some content types.  Is it possible?

I am working with Drupal 6.x.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According my test you can use two ways:

**1)** rewrite [theme_filefield_widget_file()](http://api.lullabot.com/theme_filefield_widget_file) function inside your template.php of your theme, to replace the $element['#description'] value, for example:

```
function phptemplate_filefield_widget_file($element) {
  $output = '';

  switch ($element['#name']) {
    case 'NAME_FIELD'://name of field in $element['#name']
        $element['#description'] = 'Images must be larger than 200x200';
        break;
    }


  $output .= '<div class="filefield-upload clear-block">';

  if (isset($element['#field_prefix'])) {
    $output .= $element['#field_prefix'];
  }

  _form_set_class($element, array('form-file'));
  $output .= '<input type="file" name="'. $element['#name'] .'"'. ($element['#attributes'] ? ' '. drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) : '') .' id="'. $element['#id'] .'" size="'. $element['#size'] ."\" />\n";

  if (isset($element['#field_suffix'])) {
    $output .= $element['#field_suffix'];
  }

  $output .= '</div>';

  return theme('form_element', $element, $output);
}
```

(I found very useful to change all file/image fields, but in the example the switch/case allows select an specific field that can be of your content type)

**2)** `form_alter` hook in a custom module (in this example module name is change_form_values_form_alter), and attach a function to `$form['#after_build']` array:

```
function change_form_values_form_alter($form, &$form_state) {

    if ($form['form_id']['#id'] == 'YOUR_FORM_ID') {
        $form['#after_build'][] = 'change_form_values_file_widget';
    }

}

function change_form_values_file_widget($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['GROUP_NAME_IF_EXIST']['FILE_FIELD_NAME'][0]['upload']['#description'] = 'Images must be larger than 200x200';
    return $form;
}
```

Also, seems that all help string, including other validations like max size, extensions allowed, are overwritten, so I guess that you should add the string including other texts.

I hope information be useful.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [string overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module or a hook_form_alter and override the text with

```
$form['PHOTO_FIELD_NAME']['#description'] = 'Images must be larger than 200x200';
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but I tested and the code didn't work for me.  It works:  $form['PHOTO_FIELD_NAME'][0]['upload']['#description']= 'Images must be larger than 200x200';